# Change image on home page according to time of day with CSS?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I am attempting to create the following:

I have five svg´s, each of them representing a different time in the day. Morning, Midday, Afternoon, etc.

Is it possible to make the image change depending of what time it is at the users location? If yes, is this possible with CSS only? (I am only familiar with HTML and CSS so far). If not, what would be the easiest way to achieve it in general?

All posts or threads I have found so far used other languages.

Edit: [image]

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some things incorrect on the code you wrote in the comment, you dont need to use innerHTML, just use `document.getElementById("img").src` instead of that.

One good tip using JavaScript, is to put it on a function, and call to that function when page is loaded. If you use cpoy this code, it should work correctly:

```
window.onload = changeImage;

function changeImage() {
    const time = new Date().getHours();

    if (time < 6) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "img/meerkat_five.svg";
    } else if (time < 9) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "img/meerkat_one.svg";
    } else if (time < 14) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "img/meerkat_two.svg";
    } else if (time < 17) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "img/meerkat_three.svg";
    } else if (time < 20) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "img/meerkat_four.svg";
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me here. I used your code but I get all five svg shown at the same time. I´ve now tried anything I can think of and made sure that script and html are correct. Just can´t get it to work. Also when I look at the big picture the logic in my code seems right.

Comment: Edit: It seems like I got it working "50%". I get the correct image according to time shown first. Also when I changed time the function itself works. However, all the other images also still appear in the div. Any more advice? I feel stuck :-D

Comment: Can you put an image of how does it look like dor you? What u say you are watching makes no sense in my head. I recommend you to use: `console.log(time)` in differents part of the code, to see the numer and if it is correct. I have tried the same code on my pc, and works correctly. I have seen there is a mistake on my publication,  `document.getElementById("img").src = "/img/meerkat_five.svg";` don't need the "/" on the beginning. It must be like this: `document.getElementById("img").src = "/img/meerkat_five.svg";`

Comment: Added a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: In your html, you have to many `<img src="./img/meerkat_one.svg" id="img">`, just let one and it should work propertly. I want to add you that you shouldnt use same id in different tags, it will make strange things.

Comment: Ok, it´s working. It was the html. Thanks a lot for your help!!! Learned something new again. Do you mind answering me one more question? What´s the reason that it now works even though I only have one of five svg´s in my html? Is the function looking into the same folder as meerkat_one.svg to see if there is the specified meerkat_two.svg and so on? One more thing to add for anyone reading this looking for the same solution. I had to add one more "else if" with "time < 24" and the respective imgage at the end.

Comment: What this code is doing, is to get the time in the current place you are, and then it compares with the `if` statements you put. When it goes in one of them, it changes the photo you put in your html, with the photo you have in the JavaScript. When you had five `<img>` all of them were changed with the JavaScript, but what you want is to have one image, that changes every time, depending the time. If this was helpful, i would appreciate to mark the answer like solution.

Comment: Got it, much appreciated!! Will mark it of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for making this, you can create a new file .js, or just add JavaScript in your html, between `<script>` tags.

You should take the hour its actually, using this function:

```
<script type=»text/javascript»>

var date = new Date();
var hour = (date.getHours());

</script>
```

Then you just can compare the hour you get with the time you want, and change the image:

```
<script type=»text/javascript»>

var date = new Date();
var hour = (date.getHours());

if (hour > 12) {
     document.getElementById("img").src="img/day.png";
}

</script>
```

In your html, you must have a

```
<img id="img" src="img/picture.png">
```

You just will need to change the if statements, and put the hours you prefer.

Comment: ```
const time = new Date().getHours();
let img;
if (time < 6) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = src="/img/meerkat_five.svg";
} else if (time < 9) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = src="/img/meerkat_one.svg";
} else if (time < 14) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = src="/img/meerkat_two.svg";
} else if (time < 17) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = src="/img/meerkat_three.svg";
} else if (time < 20) {
  document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = src="/img/meerkat_four.svg";
}

```
Is this looking right?